# How to get USB-Audio with Boss-RC300 working on Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: sound, usb, drivers

I have a BOSS RC-300 and i want to use it as a USB-Soundcard with Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. I got audio working by changing `sound/usb quirks-table.h` and recompiling the Kernel with 12.04 as descibed in http://org0ne.livejournal.com/29979.html.
Since i updated to 14.04 the device seems gets regognized by the system but i cannot hear any sound:

`$ lsusb | grep Roland 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0582:0138 Roland Corp. Boss RC-300 (Audio mode)`

`$ cat /proc/asound/cards | grep -A 1 USB 
[RC300          ]: USB-Audio - RC-300
                   BOSS RC-300 at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, high speed`

When selecting RC-300 in the Alsamixer i can choose between 
`Light` - and `Heavy Load  <MIDI Input Mode >` but it shows neither a volume slider nor the Chip used by the device.

My question is how can i get the device to work, at best without having to redo the procedure after every system-update. Maybe an android kernel patch, which should add Audio/Midi support for the device, could be useful: https://sourceforge.net/p/android-x86/kernel/ci/aafe77cc45a595ca1d4536f2412ddf671ea9108c/

Thanks in advice for any help.